# How to append a span properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to have an icon of valid or error appended to the input just like http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-validation , so i wrote this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[name=c_password]').keyup(password_check);

});

function password_check(){  
    $('input[name=c_password]').parent().removeClass("has-error has-feedback").removeClass("has-success has-feedback");
    var password = $('input[name=password]').val();
    var c_password = $('input[name=c_password]').val();
    if(c_password != password || c_password.length < 6){
        //alert("test");
        $('input[name=c_password]').parent().addClass( "has-error has-feedback" ).append("<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback'></span>");
    } else {
        $('input[name=c_password]').parent().addClass( "has-success has-feedback" ).append("<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback'></span>");;

    }
}
```

But instead, on the input,as soon as it is valid it added the "OK" icon above the "remove" icon ! I know there's a `remove()` method that removes the `append()`. How do I added it so that my code run perfectly?

Thanks

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/3223/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can select the span and remove.

```
$('span.glyphicon').remove()
```

http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/3227/

Comment: This is the solution to OPs question, but I'd recommend adding and removing the class from the `<span>` rather than adding and removing the whole `<span>` from the DOM

Comment: i´d recommend to use fontawesome and just change class of icon

Answer (score 0):

Just add after //alert("test");

$('input[name=c_password]').parent().addClass( "has-error has-feedback").find("span").remove();

This line finds any span tag, and removes it.

Previous answer may remove another span in the document, which may not be desired!

Comment: Thanks by corrections,  Robin van der Knaap. My english is too bad :(